# R:Define data frames in a similar space

Tags: r, dataframe, spaces

Is there a way in R to define data frames in a similar space.

So lets say I have an unknown number of data frames to be created (say there will be n data.frames) 
I want to define a space as such:

```
space<-data.frame.space()
for(i in 1:n) (
space[i]<-some.func(var1,var2)
)|
```

where some.func creates certain data.frames (in this case it downloads information from the internet), and then I get to call these data frames by saying

```
space[1] #or
space[2]
#etc
```

I know people somehow use environments for this, and in functions I see something of the sort. I just don't know how they do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a simple list

```
space<-list()
for(i in 1:n) (
    space[[i]]<-some.func(var1,var2)
)
```

and then

```
space[[1]]
space[[2]]
```

Note the double bracket indexing. Using double brackets will return the `data.frame`. Using single brackets will return a list containing the `data.frame`.